# How to get Auth code in api call post on ruby on rails app from wix api website?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, velo

I'm trying to developing a dashboard website for a `wix` application and I need to connect the website to the `wix` application.

I have a problem with an api (post) call. I have to fill in several information including the auth code that I don't know where to find.

Here is an image to illustrate the process :

[image]

I don't really know what is the `wix` app marker install, but for the authorization request I did this

```
    $url_oauth = "https://www.wix.com/oauth/access"
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(url: $url_oauth, method: :post, body:{grant_type: "authorization_code",client_id:"APP_ID", client_secret:"Secret_key", code:"{Can not find what is this value}"})
    @data = JSON.parse(response)
    render json: response
```

Here is the documentation :

[image]

Could you help how and where to find this Auth code ?

Comment: For this first image, here it the website associated : 
https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/getting-started/authentication

Comment: For the second image, here is the website associated : https://dev.wix.com/api/rest/authorization

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make an intermediate web service that will accept webhooks from WIX.
I'll show you the example of C# ASP.Net Core.
STEP 1:
We are waiting for a token from WIX and if it is received, we make a redirect.

```
private const string AppID = "";
private const string ApiKey = "";
private const string UrlAccess = "https://www.wix.com/oauth/access";
            
HttpGet("WaitToken")]
public ActionResult GetToken([FromQuery] string token = "")
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {
            string message = "Your message";
            ModelState.AddModelError("TokenNotCorrect", message);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        string paramUrl = @"https://your web service/OAuth/api/check/WaitAuthCode";
        string urlRedirect = $@"https://www.wix.com/installer/install?token={token}&appId={AppID}&redirectUrl={paramUrl}";
        return RedirectPermanent(urlRedirect);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("GetTokenException", ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

STEP 2:
We are waiting for the Auth Code to be received, provided that the user has confirmed the installation of the application.

```
[HttpGet("WaitAuthCode")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAuthCodeAsync([FromQuery] string code = "", string state = "", string instanceId = "")
{
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code))
        {
            string message = "your message";
            ModelState.AddModelError("AuthCodeNotCorrect", message);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var token = new Token(code);
        if (!GetAccessToken(ref token))
            return BadRequest("your message RefreshToken");

        var tokenBase = new TokenBase
        {
            AppID = instanceId,
            Token = token.RefreshToken
        };

        db.Tokens.Add(tokenBase);
        if(await db.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
            return BadRequest("your message");

        string urlRedirect = $"https://www.wix.com/installer/token-received?access_token={token.AccessToken}";
        return RedirectPermanent(urlRedirect);
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("GetAuthCodeException", ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

The AuthCode is valid for 10 minutes, we send a request to receive a Refresh Token. This token must be kept at home, as it will be required in the future to obtain an Access Token.

```
private bool GetAccessToken(ref Token token)
{
    try
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token, Formatting.Indented);

        var client = new RestClient(UrlAccess);
        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter(string.Empty, json, "application/json", ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var response = client.Post(request);
        if (response == null)
            return false;
            
        token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(response.Content);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.RefreshToken))
            return false;
            
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.AccessToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Getting an Access Token from a client application:

```
[HttpGet("WaitAccessToken")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetAccessToken([FromQuery] string instance = "", string apiKey = "")
{
    string message;

    var tokenBase = await db.Tokens.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AppID == instance);
    if (tokenBase == null)
    {
        message = "Your message";
        ModelState.AddModelError("AppIdNotFound", message);
        return NotFound(ModelState);
    }

    var token = new Token
    {
        GrantType = "refresh_token",
        RefreshToken = tokenBase.Token
    };

    if (!GetAccessToken(ref token))
    {
        message = $"Your message";
        ModelState.AddModelError("NotCorrectAccessToken", message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    return new ObjectResult(token.AccessToken);
}
```

Model Token:

```
public class Token
{
    public Token() { }

    public Token(string code) { Code = code; }

    [JsonProperty("grant_type")]
    public string GrantType { get; set; } = "authorization_code";

    [JsonProperty("client_id")]
    public string ClientID { get; set; } = "";
    
    [JsonProperty("client_secret")]
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; } = "";
    
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("access_token", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Model Instance:

```
public class Instance
{

    [JsonProperty("instanceId")]
    public string InstanceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("appDefId")]
    public string AppDefId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("signDate")]
    public DateTime SignDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("permissions")]
    public string Permissions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("demoMode")]
    public bool DemoMode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("siteOwnerId")]
    public string SiteOwnerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("siteMemberId")]
    public string SiteMemberId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expirationDate")]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("loginAccountId")]
    public string LoginAccountId { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget that to get an Access Token, you will need the application ID on the site where it is installed.

```
[HttpGet("WixInfo")]
public ActionResult GetWixInfo([FromQuery] string instance = "")
{
    try
    {
        string message;
        var base64 = instance.Split(".");
        if (base64.Length != 2)
        {
            message = "Your message";
            ModelState.AddModelError("InstanceNotCorrect", message);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64[1]);
        string json = Encoding.Default.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        var info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Instance>(json);

        message = $"Your message.AppID: {info.InstanceId}";
        return Ok(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("GetWixInfoException", ex.Message);
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

When a WIX application is launched by a user, you can get the ID of the running application.